# Installing tensorflow on virtualbox ubuntu 20.04 python 2.7 - 'Illegal instruction (core dumped)'

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, virtualbox, ubuntu-20.04

my goal is to follow this [guide](https://ndres.me/post/convert-caffe-to-tensorflow/) so that I can convert a Caffe model to a Tensorflow model. As my original OS is Windows 10 I am using the virtual Ubuntu 20.04 (using Oracle VirtualBox) with python 2.7 and anaconda virtual env. I am able to successfully install tensorflow for python 2.7, but when I run the command `python -c 'import tensorflow'`, I get an error with text `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`. I have tried to google to get more information but all I got was that it maybe has something to do with the architecture, I found out that my architecture (on the virtual ubuntu) is `x86_64`. That is all I have found out and now I turned to SO to ask what I should do to be able to run tensorflow in the before described environment, many thanks beforehand.

Comment: The solution provided by Micheal Krocka should work, conda somehow has a pre compiled binaries or something. Not very sure about it. 

Another workaround is to use linux subsytem for windows instead of virtualbox. You follow similar steps as linux machine. Get the tensflow libraries compiled with pip.

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering, the pip or conda installation did not work in my case, so I followed the instructions on this [guide](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/+/r0.10/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md) for linux, python 2.7 using the pip installation method with a tensorflow version of 0.10, which for my purposes is good enough.

Exact steps in case the link does not work in the future:

- `$ conda create -n tensorflow python=2.7`
- `$ conda activate tensorflow`
- Your prompt should change to this: `(tensorflow)$`
- `(tensorflow)$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`
- `(tensorflow)$ pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL`

This is, as outlined, for python 2.7, but the guide contains info for newer versions as well. To check whether tensorflow installed correctly you can run this command `$ python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'` which should output `0.10.0`.